# Tkinter Checkbox click animation color changes

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a check box, and the Tkinter window and the check box's background is white:

```
from tkinter import *

root =Tk()
root.config(bg='white')
x = IntVar(value=0)
checkbox = Checkbutton(variable=x, text='check me')
checkbox.config(bg='white')
checkbox.pack()

mainloop()
```

When you click on it, it turns gray. How do I make it so that it doesn't turn gray (make it white the whole time)? Thanks :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use `activebackground="white"` like this:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.config(bg="white")
x = IntVar(master=root, value=0)
checkbox = Checkbutton(root, variable=x, text="check me",
                       activebackground="white")
checkbox.config(bg="white")
checkbox.pack()

root.mainloop()
```